# Conditional statement sleep

Tags: java

Why do I get "Deficiency" instead of "Normal"?

Given three numbers: A, B and H.
According to Doctor report:

- one should sleep at least A hours per day,
- but no more than B hours.
- H is how many hours Anna sleeps.

Task:

- If Anna sleeps less then A hours, print "Deficiency".
- If she sleeps more than BB hours, print "Excess".
- If her sleep fits the recommendations, print "Normal".

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int units = input.nextInt();

     
        int a = input.nextInt();
        int b = input.nextInt();
        int h = b - a;

        if (h < a ){
            System.out.println("Deficiency");
        } else if (h > b) {
            System.out.println("Excess");
        } else if (h == 8){
            System.out.println("Normal");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What are your inputs? Shouldn't you also input a number for `h`? Why are you calculating `h` as `b - a`?

Comment: If `b` is more than `2a`, you'll get a deficiency.

Comment: Also, why are you assuming that the amount of sleep is only normal if it's exactly 8 hours? That's not what the requirements say, and it happens to be untrue because 8 hours is only an average - some people may need a lot more or a lot less than that.

Comment: @ - maloomeister: Sample Input:

6
10
8

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you just simplify it like this?

- First, check that she didn't sleep too little.
- Then if she didn't, ensure she didn't sleep too much.
- Then by exclusion, no test is required so she must have slept normally.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int tooLittle = input.nextInt();
int tooMuch = input.nextInt();
int hoursSlept = input.nextInt();

if (hoursSlept <= tooLittle ){
    System.out.println("Deficiency");
} else if (hoursSlept >= tooMuch) {
    System.out.println("Excess");
} else {
    System.out.println("Normal");
}
```

Notice that the difference between what is `tooMuch` and `tooLittle` has nothing to do with how much Anna slept.  So you also need to prompt for that value.

Answer (score 3):

You mentioned that "H is how many hours Ann sleeps." but I see from your code that you're calculating **H** at this line:

```
int h = b - a;
```

in which case **h** will **ALWAYS** be smaller than **a** hence triggering the first if statement:

```
if (h < a ){
    System.out.println("Deficiency");
}
```

To fix this, get an input for **h** as well and then see if it's in normal range. This should work:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int units = input.nextInt();

     
        int a = input.nextInt();
        int b = input.nextInt();
        int h = input.nextInt(); // get an input for Ann's sleep time

        if (h < a ){
            System.out.println("Deficiency");
        } else if (h > b) {
            System.out.println("Excess");
        } else if (h >= a && h <= b) // h must fall between a and b ranges to be considered normal
        {
            System.out.println("Normal");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `h` won't be less than `a` in the case that `b >= 2a`, so your second statement isn't really true. Otherwise, this seems to correct the problems in the OP's code.

Comment: Also, they should include `print` statements explaining to the user what input they're supposed to enter (rather than just prompting them 3 times).

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really match what the requirements say. You should get an input for `h` - you can't compute it from `a` or `b` because they're constants for what they're *supposed* to be getting; they have nothing to do with what they *actually* get.

If `a < 2b`, you'll always get a deficiency. Otherwise, you'll always get "excess" (except in the special case where `b - a = 8`, in which case you'll get "normal"; also, in the case where `a = b`, you won't print anything at all).

The third case (hardcoding it to h == 8) doesn't meet the requirements and isn't really true. Not only does the requirements not say that 8 hours of sleep is normal, it's not even true - 8 hours of sleep is only an average - some people might need somewhat more or somewhat less than that. The requirements say to check to see if `h` is between `a` and `b`, not to check to see if it's exactly 8 hours.

Also, from a user input perspective, you should prompt the user for input, like this:

```
System.out.println("Enter the minimum amount of sleep:");
int a = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter the maximum amount of sleep:");
int b = input.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter the actual amount of sleep:");
int h = input.nextInt();
```

Finally, you never actually use `unit`, so this is either unnecessary or there's a requirement you forgot to implement.